# VBA - filling array with a class of dictionaries

Tags: vba

I have created a class of dictionary objects.  I then initialize the class and put three blank copies into an array.   I then go ahead and fill in some of the dictionary values within the array.  The behavior isn't what I expected.

After running the code I expected the array to fill in such that 
 VersionAry(1) holds one item in each dictionary, VersionAry(2) holds one item in each dictionary, and VersionAry(3) remains empty.

Instead each array element holds the identical two items.

It seems like this line:

```
VersionAry(1).dictDate.Add 1, 201501
```

actually adds 1, 201501 to the dictDate dictionary in VersionAry(1), VersionAry(2), and VersionAry(3) instead of just to VersionAry(1) which is my goal.

class code:

```
'Class Module named: cDailyData

Public dictDate As Object
Public dictTotal As Object
Public dictFees As Object

Public Sub Init()
    Set dictDate = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set dictTotal = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set dictFees = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
End Sub
```

module code:

```
'Module Code
Sub ModuleCode2()
Dim clsDailyResults As cDailyData

Dim VersionAry() As Variant
ReDim VersionAry(1 To 3)

Set clsDailyResults = New cDailyData
clsDailyResults.Init

For i = 1 To 3
    Set VersionAry(i) = clsDailyResults
Next i

VersionAry(1).dictDate.Add 1, 201501
VersionAry(1).dictFees.Add 1, 100
VersionAry(1).dictTotal.Add 1, 1000

VersionAry(2).dictDate.Add 2, 201501
VersionAry(2).dictFees.Add 2, 200
VersionAry(2).dictTotal.Add 2, 2000

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You're adding the same object into the array multiple times. The Dictionaries already hold your index, so you can just access them directly.  The Class would be a lot more useful if you gave them properties for Date, Fees, and Total, then stored multiple instances of *cDailyData* in a dictionary or an array.  The class should probably look more like this:

```
'Class Module named: cDailyData
Option Explicit

Private m_date As Long
Private m_fees As Long
Private m_total As Long

Public Property Let Day(in_value As Long)
    m_date = in_value
End Property

Public Property Get Day() As Long
    Day = m_date
End Property

Public Property Let Total(in_value As Long)
    m_total = in_value
End Property

Public Property Get Total() As Long
    Total = m_total
End Property

Public Property Let Fees(in_value As Long)
    m_fees = in_value
End Property

Public Property Get Fees() As Long
    Fees = m_fees
End Property
```

If your keys are non-sequential and unique, a Dictionary would be appropriate and the Module would look like this:

```
Sub ModuleCode2()

    Dim VersionDict As New Dictionary
    Dim result As New cDailyData

    result.Day = 201501
    result.Fees = 100
    result.Total = 1000

    VersionDict.Add 1, result

    Set result = New cDailyData
    result.Day = 201501
    result.Fees = 200
    result.Total = 2000

    VersionDict.Add 2, result

    Dim key As Variant
    For Each key In VersionDict.Keys
        Debug.Print VersionDict(key).Fees
    Next key

End Sub
```

If you don't really care what the key is and just need an array of cDailyData, that would look more like this:

```
Sub ModuleCode2a()
    Dim VersionAry() As cDailyData
    ReDim VersionAry(1 To 3)

    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To 3
        Set VersionAry(i) = New cDailyData
    Next i

    VersionAry(1).Day = 201501
    VersionAry(1).Fees = 100
    VersionAry(1).Total = 1000

    VersionAry(2).Day = 201501
    VersionAry(2).Fees = 200
    VersionAry(2).Total = 2000

    For i = 1 To 3
        Debug.Print VersionAry(i).Fees
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: I see what you did there but it doesn't get me to where I want to be.  I have arrays of Day, Fees, and Total that I will populate as they are cacluated.  There will also be X versions of these arrays (VersionAry).

Then within each VersionAry will be the cDailyData class that holds individual dictionaries of fees, total and date.  Basically many versions will exist, each version with unique lists of fees, total and date.

Comment: So the heirarchy would look like this...

VersionAry(1 to 3)  --> cDailyData class --> dictionary.fees, dictionary.total, dictionary.date

What confuses me is that the I would think that 

    VersionAry(1).dictFees.Add 1, 10

wouldn't also show up in VersionAry(2), but that seems to be what is happening.

Comment: @mike212 - It's showing up in all of the array elements because it's the same object. You only instantiate one copy of cDailyData, then point 3 array elements at the same thing. If you need a Dictionary of Day/Fee/Total in each array element, I'd recommend using an array of Dictionaries and filling them with class implementation above.

Comment: Thank you.  This led me to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the code to create a new class each time and that seems to work

```
For i = 1 To 3
    Set clsDailyResults = New cDailyData
    clsDailyResults.Init
    Set VersionAry(i) = clsDailyResults
Next i
```

instead of

```
Set clsDailyResults = New cDailyData
clsDailyResults.Init

For i = 1 To 3
    Set VersionAry(i) = clsDailyResults
Next i
```